# Is there any way to speed up this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with a field "Transtype", which is either "GAME_BET" or "GAME_WIN" and a field "AmountReal" that I have to sum, as a negative (-) if Transtype is GAME_WIN or Positive (+) is Transtype= GAME_BET

My query is as follow:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.GameBet-t1.GameWin) as result from 
(SELECT 
if (TranType='GAME_BET',AmountReal,0 ) as GameBet,
if (TranType='GAME_WIN',-AmountReal,0) as GameWin
FROM DataFeed_test
WHERE Datetime >='2019-08-01') t1
```

Is there a way to execute this query faster (lots of rows to process!) and potentially to avoid intermediary table t1?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. In addition, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: We'd also need to know your indexes and types. It doesn't affect this particular query because you've stored it ISO 8601 style, but `Datetime` being a string will bite you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the subquery and directly use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT sum(CASE trantype
             WHEN 'GAME_BET' THEN
               amountreal
             WHEN 'GAME_WIN' THEN
               -amountreal
             ELSE
               0
           END) result
       FROM datafeed_test
       WHERE datetime >= '2019-08-01';
```

To speed it up put and index on `datafeed_test (datetime)` to support the `WHERE` clause. You can also try a compound index on `datafeed_test (datetime, trantype, amountreal)`.

Comment: way simpler. Thanks a lot